# Mark 7:18-19 Common or unclean?

Tags: greek

Mark 7:18-19 has been debated in other questions, but not one seems to have addressed the distinction between the words common vs unclean.

The webpage (link below, see point #2 on webpage) seems to make a valid argument that the **incorrect** translation of the greek word [**koinōsai**] in verse 18  is "**unclean**" but that the correct translation is "**common**".

This would mean that Jesus was not cancelling the Law (which would have resulted in an immediate fight) but instead was addressing the Pharisees' traditions (which created manmade, Jewish made customs, that define what common is, apart from the Law). This improved translation  as  common would also better follow the issue of "common" that Jesus was addressing in the previous verses.

What do you think? Does this give an improved understanding of Mark 7 in general, and Mark 7:18-19 specifically?

Al

See reason #2 at this link: 
https://messianicpublications.com/robert-roy/did-jesus-declare-all-foods-clean/

Comment: Why would Jesus say that eating something 'cannot make him common' ? ου δυναται αυτον κοινωσαι. The issue is about sanctified service and eating something that would render the service unacceptable. Therefore, to the dedicated worshipper, eating something that render's one's service to God unacceptable : is a defilement. The word 'common' in English does not bear the meaning 'profane', which is perhaps an alternative to 'defiled'.

Answer (score 1):

Peter said, By no means, Lord, for I have never eaten anything common and unclean. 
And a voice came to him again a second time: The things that God has cleansed, do not make common. Sounds like they're synonyms in the contexts.

He said to them, Are you also in the same manner without understanding? Do you not understand that everything that enters from outside into a man is not able to defile him, because it does not enter into his heart, but into the stomach, and goes out into the drain? (In saying this, He made all foods clean.) And He said, That which goes out of the man, that defiles the man. For from within, out of the heart of men, proceed evil reasonings, fornications, thefts, murders, adulteries, covetousness, wickedness, deceit, licentiousness, envy, blasphemy, arrogance, foolishness. All these wicked things proceed from within and defile the man.

"Defile," "unclean," "common," it looks like they're all the opposite of "clean" in 19. The things listed in 21-22 are the opposite of clean. Mark, written around AD 67 on Peter's behalf I understand, confirms the apostle's revelation and experience (though foods there in Acts 10 are also an allegory for humans).

Answer (score 1):

I will not comment on the matter of whether Torah food laws are binding or not.  I will stick to the meaning of the operative word in Mark 7:18, namely, κοινῶσαι (koinosai) with the root word, κοινόω (koinoo), a verb meaning "to make common".

[Note, the cognate adjective, κοινός (koinos) means "common"].

Strictly speaking, the verb κοινόω (koinoo) is "to make common".  However, and this is the crux of the matter, the Jews were called to be a separate and distinct people that were holy and undefiled.  This is stated unambiguously at the giving of the 10 commandments at Mt Sinai in Ex 19:5, 6 which says:

> Now then, if you will indeed obey My voice and keep My covenant, then
>   you shall be My own possession among all the peoples, for all the
>   earth is Mine; and you shall be to Me a kingdom of priests and a holy
>   nation.

When Peter was called to go to the centurion's house, he would have objected because devout Jews were not allowed to even set foot inside a gentile's house (Acts 10:28) but the message of his vision had shown him that no such distinction should be made (v28, 29).

Thus, the Jews regarded "common" things as defiled and unclean.  Hence BDAG lists (#2) the most frequent meaning of κοινόω (koinoo) as "***make common or impure, defile*** in the cultic sense".  In Acts 10:15, 11:9 it is used in the sense of considering something (ritually) unclean.

There is no English word that carries quite the same meaning as the Greek κοινός (koinos).  The closest we come is the older English meaning of "profane" in contradistinction to "sacred" or "holy".